# How to know when an order gets open(date and time) in woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

PHP:

order status is wc_open and I am trying to find out the way to know when an order gets open(date and time).

```
$order = wc_get_order( $nextorder->ID );

$order->get_date_modified();
```

I am using `get_date_modified()` but this method not giving correct answer because modified date changed if any change happens.

Please help me.

Comment: wc_open is a custom order status not by defalt in woocommerce… So you need  please to give all the necessary related details in your question about, as mostly nobody can guess that... If not your question is just unclear and off-topic in StackOverFlow.

Comment: I need to know date time when an order status change from process to open in woocommerce.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. "wc_open is a custom order status not by defalt in woocommerce"

Comment: So where is the related code or the details and information about it… please **update your question**. Nobody can guess that. Also your code is incomplete and not testable. Remember that *"Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error **and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself**"*.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do it like this:

```
$order = wc_get_order($nextorder->ID);
$order_date = $order->order_date;
```

Comment: I want to know open_date not order_date

Comment: wc-open date time